# Feynman rules with other propagators$.$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, propagator

An arbitrary correlation function
$$
G_F(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\langle 0|\mathrm T\ \phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)|0\rangle\tag1
$$
can be calculated in perturbation theory by adding all Feynman diagrams, with the rule that internal lines correspond to the symmetric propagator
$$
\Delta_F\sim\frac{1}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\tag2
$$

Define the function
$$
G_\Delta(x_1,\dots,x_n)\tag3
$$
as the object given by the same Feynman diagrams as $(1)$ but using an arbitrary propagator $\Delta$ instead of $(2)$. For example, we may use
$$
\Delta_\mathrm{adv}\sim\frac{1}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon p^0}\quad\text{or}\quad \Delta_\mathrm{ret}\sim\frac{1}{p^2-m^2-i\epsilon p^0}\tag4
$$

If we use a covariant propagator, it is clear that $G_\Delta$ is covariant as well. I am interested in other properties of $G_\Delta$ inherited from the corresponding properties of the associated $\Delta$. In particular,

**Question 1:** Is $G_\Delta$ symmetric if we use a propagator that is not? in other words, if $\Delta(-x)\neq\Delta(x)$, may we have $G_\Delta(x_1,\dots,x_n)=G_\Delta(x_{\pi_1},\dots,x_{\pi_n})$ for any permutation $\pi$?

**Question 2:** How are the boundary conditions of $\Delta$ reflected in the boundary conditions of $G_\Delta$? e.g., is $G_{\Delta_\mathrm{adv}}(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ for $x^0_i<0$?

---

More generally, one may wonder what "nice" properties we lose if we use some $\Delta\neq \Delta_F$, such as

- Cluster properties (factorisation for $|x_i-x_j|\to\infty$).
- Expansion in irreducible functions (can $G_\Delta$ be written as an expansion in terms of irreducible diagrams?).

but these questions seem rather non-trivial so I don't expect answers to attempt to address them here.

Comment: Wick's theorem implies that $G_\Delta$ is, to tree level, a symmetric linear combination of $\Delta$'s, which means that it should have the same properties as $\Delta$ (e.g., if the latter is not symmetric, the former won't be either). I guess loop corrections will not spoil this fact.